# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j.topic()

Tags: log4j, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am getting following error when I annotate a class with @Log4j. The same version set is working with other project.

Error:

```
[javac] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j.topic()Ljava/lang/String;  
[javac] at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleLog$HandleLog4jLog.handle(HandleLog.java:132)
```

Versions:

```
Lombok - 1.12 
Log4j - 1.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the exact Lombok version, but `topic` has been introduced in 1.12.6. Possibly this feature has not made it yet to the IntelliJ plugin. Possibly using an 1.12.4 solves this problem.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: This could be the reason. I made some more changes actually with up-gradation of versions, so not sure of the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Lombok 1.16.x, and I have included LombokUtils and LombokApi accordingly.

Then it worked.